# line 18, col 11, Expected '{' and instead saw '$scope'

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) in my simple angular js project but when I try to do `npm install` I get the error below

> js/controllers/HomePageController.js: line 18, col 11, Expected '{'
>   and instead saw '$scope'. js/controllers/HomePageController.js: line
>   23, col 4, Missing semicolon.

My JS folder is like below

```
.
├── app_module.js
├── controllers
│   └── HomePageController.js
└── directives
    ├── GreetBox.js
    └── HomePageGreetingBox.js
```

and I have the following code in `HomePageController.js`

```
angular.module('app').controller('HomePageController', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
  'use strict';

    $scope.greetingText = 'Get to somehrere!';

    $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
          url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
          data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
        });

        file.upload.then(function (response) {
          $timeout(function () {
            file.result = response.data;
          });
        }, function (response) {
          if (response.status > 0)
            $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
          // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
          file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
    }   

}]);
```

and the code in `app_module.js` is below

```
;(function (angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app', []);
})(angular);
```

**Removing use string**
Gives the following error

```
➜  angular-skeleton git:(master) ✗ npm install && node server.js

> angular-skeleton@0.0.0 postinstall /Users/anthony/code/angular/angular-skeleton
> bower install && node_modules/.bin/gulp

bower angular         extra-resolution Unnecessary resolution: angular#~1.5.0
[12:37:40] Using gulpfile ~/code/angular/angular-skeleton/gulpfile.js
[12:37:40] Starting 'clean'...
[12:37:40] Finished 'clean' after 4.22 ms
[12:37:40] Starting 'lint'...
[12:37:40] Starting 'views'...
[12:37:40] Starting 'app'...
[12:37:40] Starting 'vendor'...
[12:37:40] Starting 'css'...
[12:37:40] Finished 'css' after 6.84 ms
js/controllers/HomePageController.js: line 2, col 5, Missing "use strict" statement.
js/controllers/HomePageController.js: line 16, col 13, Expected '{' and instead saw '$scope'.
js/controllers/HomePageController.js: line 21, col 6, Missing semicolon.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the 'use strict';

```
angular.module('app').controller('HomePageController', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.greetingText = 'Get to somehrere!';

    $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
          url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
          data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
        });

        file.upload.then(function (response) {
          $timeout(function () {
            file.result = response.data;
          });
        }, function (response) {
          if (response.status > 0)
            $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
          // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
          file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
    }   

}]);
```

Comment: Now I get an error `Missing "use strict" statement.`

Comment: it should come outside

Comment: sorry, outside where? Im new to AngularJS

Comment: do you have team viewer? or share your code on plunker

Comment: I've just installed team viewer. How can I give you access to see the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134987/discussion-between-anthony-and-sajeetharan).